# How to correctly prepare Citrix ICA client object instance to make a successful connection to a farm with Citrix Access Gateway?

Tags: citrix

I am using Citrix ICA client object API to establish a connection to published applications programmatically. Typically, it is as simple as subscribing to a number of events, feeding the object with an ICA file (via LoadIcaFile method) and invoking Connect method.

However, with ICA clients 12.1 or higher, this approach leads to immediate disconnect event in case if CAG is used and ICA file's Address field contains a cryptic token instead of server IP/name. The same approach works fine with an older client (10.x) *or* if ICA file contains direct server Address (which I assume means CAG is not used)

If anyone had success in programmatic session launches against Citrix Access Gateway environments successfully working with ICA client 12.1 or higher, please share how it was done.

NOTE: my understanding of Citrix server side is very limited, from practise - I believe I met with ICA files containing cryptic Address field coming from Web Interface to farms using any of the following: citrix access gateway, citrix secure gateway, citrix netscaler

Comment: our latest findings show that ICA Client 13.1 connects just fine (like client 10.200 did) - thus issues with programmatic connection to CAG are likely to be the shortcomings of particular client versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is unlikely to have any other solutions here, so I consider my latest comment as an answer:

ICA Client 13.1 connects just fine (like client 10.200 did)

Thus issues with programmatic connections to CAG are likely to be the shortcomings (defects?) of particular client versions - so no specific preparation of ICA Client Object to work in CAG environment is necessary.